# is it true that $(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} U_i)^c = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} U_{i}^{c}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true that $(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} U_i)^c  = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} U_{i}^{c}$? Where $c$ denotes the compliment. I drew a picture for two sets and tried to convinced myself that it was true, but a more formal proof/explenation would be nice.

Comment: Note: In order for complement to make sense, you need a 'universal set' which contains all the $U_i$'s. Consider what is required for an element of this universal set to be in the LHS, what about the RHS? You should be able to see the logic pretty easily from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**De Morgan's laws** give you that $(A \bigcap B)^c = A^c \bigcup B^c$ ($\star$). It can easily be verified as follows:
\begin{align*}
x \in (A \bigcap B)^c \iff x \not\in A\bigcap B \iff x \not\in A \text{ or } x \not\in B \iff x \in A^c \bigcup B^c
\end{align*}

Now let us prove by induction on $n$ that  $ \mathcal{P}(n) : (\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} U_i)^c  = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} U_{i}^{c}$ is true for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose $\mathcal{P}(n-1)$ is true. Then use ($\star$):

$(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} U_i)^c = ((\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} U_i) \bigcap U_n)^c = (\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} U_i)^c \bigcup U_n^c = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} U_{i}^{c}\bigcup U_n^c = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} U_{i}^{c}$

Thus $\mathcal{P}(n)$ is true, yielding that $\mathcal{P}(n)$ is true for every $n$ by induction.

Answer (score 2):

$$x\in\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^nU_i\right)^c\iff x\notin\bigcap_{i=1}^nU_i\iff\cdots\iff x\in\bigcup_{i=1}^nU_i^c$$

Try to work this out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove this by doing the inclusions from left to right and right to left.

1. Let $x \in \left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n U_i\right)^c$. This means there exists some index $j$ such that $x \notin U_j$. Hence $x \in U_j^c$ and therefore $x \in \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n U_i^c$. Therefore $\left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n U_i\right)^c \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n U_i^c$.
2. Let $x \in \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n U_i^c$. Then there is some $j$ such that $x \in U_j^c$. Hence $x \notin U_j$ and thus $x \notin \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n U_i$. Thus $x \in \left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n U_i\right)^c$. Therefore $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n U_i^c \subseteq \left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n U_i\right)^c$.
3. Since both inclusions are true, we must have that
   $$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n U_i^c = \left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n U_i\right)^c$$